# How do I get a list of all available fonts for luaotfload?

Tags: fonts, luatex, luaotfload

luaotfload uses an internal database that gets updated with `mkluatexfontdb`. So it knows about a lot of fonts installed on my computer. How can I query this database? Something like

```
luatexfontdb --list-fonts-on-my-computer-that-are-in-your-database
```

?

Comment: No, there aren't, it is on the, not written, todo list, but don't hold your breath.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could open the database in your editor. It is called otfl-names.lua and should be in one of your texmf-trees in `\luatex-cache\generic\names`.

It is also not very difficult to make lists based on otfl-names.lua. E.g.

### Old version (Texlive 2013?)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,luaotfload}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode}
myfonts=dofile(fonts.names.path.localdir..'/otfl-names.lua')

for i,v in ipairs(myfonts.mappings) do
 tex.print(-2, v.familyname)
 tex.print(', ')
 tex.print(-2, v.fontname)
 tex.print('\\par')
end

\end{luacode}

\end{document}
```

Edit in may 2013: With a newer luaotfload (as the one in TL2013 (pretest) one should exchange the myfonts line by this one as the name of the database as changed:

```
 myfonts=dofile(fonts.names.path.path)
```

## Edit for Texlive 2014

I tried again in TL 2014 (june 2014). Now the names file is in a .luc and the access name has changed again. I also added some "if exist code" to avoid error if a table entry doesn't exist for a font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{luaotfload}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode}
myfonts=dofile(fonts.names.path.index.luc)

tex.sprint(fonts.names.path.index.luc)

---[[
for i,v in ipairs(myfonts.mappings) do
 if v.familyname then
 tex.print('\\par')
 tex.print(-2, v.familyname)
 end
 if v.fontname then 
 tex.print(', ')
 tex.print(-2, v.fontname)
 end
 tex.print('\\par')
end
--]]

\end{luacode}

\end{document}
```

## Edit for TeXlive 2015 / MiKTeX in july 2015

The code do get the names file has to be adapted again. Now this here seems to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{luaotfload}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode}
myfonts=dofile(config.luaotfload.paths.index_path_luc)

tex.sprint(config.luaotfload.paths.index_path_luc)

---[[
for i,v in ipairs(myfonts.mappings) do
 if v.familyname then
 tex.print('\\par')
 tex.print(-2, v.familyname)
 end
 if v.fontname then
 tex.print(', ')
 tex.print(-2, v.fontname)
 end
 tex.print('\\par')
end
--]]

\end{luacode}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is the best way to generate a font list at the moment, as there seems to be no tool like `fc-list` doing this job yet - see this [newsgroup entry](http://tug.org/pipermail/lualatex-dev/2010-November/000931.html).

Comment: On my Windows box with MiKTex 2.9, this code triggered warnings about missing math mode delimiters, causing lualatex to insert four `$` characters . Wrapping the string printed by `tex.print` within a `verbatim` block silenced that warning, although I don't spot *which* fonts triggered it.

Comment: The obvious suspects are fonts with underscores in their name so setting its catcode to e.g. 12 should help.

Comment: @RBerteig, @Ulrike: You can use something like `tex.tprint({-2, v.familyname, ', ', v.fontname},{-1,  '\\par'})` to get rid of the catcodes problem.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I hoped that there is an extra query tool. I'll ponder about this......

Comment: In TeX Live 2013, I can't find a file otfl-names.lua, in Windows or Linux. The `luatex-cache` folder contains `context`, and nothing else. Maybe that file only exists for LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @LarsH The name has changed. It is now called luaotfload-names.lua. And it is in texmf-var. (I didn't test if the code above still work. It is quite possible that the structure of the tables has changed too.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks, but I don't see that file either, neither on Windows nor on Linux.

Comment: @LarsH: Did you actually run once `luaotfload-tool -u`  (e.g. by compiling a document which needs the database)?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I compiled a ConTeXt LuaTeX document that attempts to access fonts (using the Simplefonts module). Does that qualify? Can I just run `luaotfload-tool -u` by hand? I tried, but can't find such a file...

Comment: @LarsH That's not a file but a script/a executable and you can simply run it on the command line. And it is part of the luaotfload package so it is latex specific and you need a latex document which uses fontspec to trigger the tool. The context cache file for font infos is (imho) the file called names.tma.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks for your response. Running `luaotfload-tool` on the command line gives me "command not found". I guess that's because I only have the ConTeXt scheme installed, not LaTeX. I just looked for `names.tma`, and found one under ~/.texlive2013. Will let you know how that goes!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11349/discussion-between-larsh-and-ulrike-fischer)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: did you tried the `myfonts=dofile(fonts.names.path.path)` for TL13/14?

Comment: @Herbert: I must have tried it when I added the comment. But inbetween luaotfload has again changed (one really needs an official interface). I will add an edit to my answer.

Comment: I'm afraid your update for TeXLive2014 bombs on a system running MacTeX2014. Error message: `! LuaTeX error [\directlua]:1: attempt to index field 'path' (a nil value)
stack traceback: [\directlua]:1: in main chunk, \luacode@dbg@exec ...code@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }`.

Comment: I get the same error as @Mico, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: It seems to be bugged for TeXLive2015 as well (same error than @mico).

Comment: This is awesome answer and last code works for MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit as well. Does anybody know how to tune it to show example text using the listed font? I have never got into lua...

Comment: When I run this with TeXLive 2019 on my system (Devuan 3.0), I get: ` String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence. l.17553 apiphon�ttique`. Is there some way to make lualatex ignore/skip this invalid sequence? Or parse what is probably an é?

Comment: With MiKTeX 22.8.28 and latest versions of all packages, I get ```("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd")cannot open
 C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc: No such file or directory
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'dofile'
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\luacode@dbg@exec ...code@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }

l.24 \end{luacode}


?```

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე use luafindfont as suggested in another answer.

Comment: This gives me `Looking for font "*"
...pData\Roaming\MiKTeX\scripts/luafindfont\luafindfont.lua:180: attempt to concatenate a nil value (field '?')`

Comment: Actually I now managed to successfully run the script from your answer! I found a file named `luaotfload-names.luc.gz` and when I gunzipped it the script worked successfully.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე `locate luaotfload-names.luc` says `luaotfload-names.luc.gz` isn't unzipped with TL 2023 but it is with TL 2019 and 2021, and I actually don't see what command I did run to make the latter unzipped (I certainly didn't do that manually).

Answer (score 15):

Based on Ulrike's answer:

Because I don't want to create a TeX document every time I need the font list, here is a simple script for that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env texlua

kpse.set_program_name("listluatexfonts")

cachefile  = kpse.expand_var("$TEXMFVAR")  .. "/luatex-cache/generic/names/otfl-names.lua"
fontlist = dofile(cachefile)
assert(fontlist,"Could not load font name database")

local tmp = {}

for _,font in ipairs(fontlist.mappings) do
  tmp[#tmp + 1] = font.fontname
end
table.sort(tmp)

for _,fontname in ipairs(tmp) do
  print(fontname)
end
```

call it with

```
./listluatexfonts
```

---

### Update:

Replace the `cachefile` name for TexLive 2014:

```
cachefile  = kpse.expand_var("$TEXMFVAR")  .. "/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc"
```

This one worked for me.

Comment: Can anyone tell how to do this with TeXLive 2013? There doesn't appear to be a `generic` directory under `luatex-cache` anymore... at least not in my installation.

Comment: OK, those folders may be specific to LuaLaTeX. See comment discussion with Ulrike.

Answer (score 5):

```
 luafindfont -n "*"
```

lists all fonts which can be used by `xelatex`/ `lualatex` without a special path setting.
-n is "no symbolic names column"

Comment: As commented to another answer, with MiKTeX 22.8.28 (under Windows 11) I get `Looking for font "*" ...pData\Roaming\MiKTeX\scripts/luafindfont\luafindfont.lua:180: attempt to concatenate a nil value (field '?')`

Comment: Please run `luafindfont -v times`  and send me the output to `hvoss@tug.org`

Comment: ok, I see the problem ...

Comment: and on CTAN is an update which will be part of MiKTeX/TeXLive in the next few days