# How to iterate through the list of installed fonts?

Tags: fonts

I am using `xelatex.exe` and need to iterate through the list of fonts installed on my Windows 7 machine. The following code is not complete because I have no idea what is the name that contains the list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1pt}
%\PreviewEnvironment{}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\myInstalledFonts{}
\begingroup
\renewcommand\<what should I put here>[<what should I put here>]{%
  \listgadd{\myInstalledFonts}{#2}%
  }
\input{<what should I put here>.def}
\endgroup

\usepackage{fontspec}

\def\do#1{%
    \setmainfont{#1}
        \begin{preview}
    I can find a tool to convert PDF to EPS
    in my neither bathroom nor kitchen.\par
        \end{preview}
}%

\begin{document}

\dolistloop{\myInstalledFonts}

\end{document}
```

How to iterate through the list of installed fonts?

Answer (score 3):

I think you will have to get the list externally, e.g. with `fc-list : file`, and then process it. With lualatex you can read `otfl-names.lua`, see e.g. [Lualatex: Font table with examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23630/lualatex-font-table-with-examples).