# Using TeX to generate renderings of letters

Tags: fonts

### Short Question:

How can I achieve the following two things:

1) Get a list of all Fonts, currently installed on my system, that LaTeX can use?

2) For each font, render the letters a-z, A-Z, 0-9.

### Longer Question:

Basically, I want to render all the glyphs that my current system can render. So I want to:

1) get a list of all the fonts that LaTeX can use and
  2) render all the glyphs in each of the fonts

How can I do this in LaTeX?

Thanks!

### EDIT

It appears the answer to part 1 of my question is

```
updmap-sys --listmaps | wc -l
```

from [What fonts are installed on my box?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/what-fonts-are-installed-on-my-box)

So for part 2. How do I use all of these fonts?

### EDIT 3

So turns out my question is a duplicate of:

[Lualatex: Font table with examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23630/lualatex-font-table-with-examples)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think that depends quite a bit on what you mean by "that LaTeX can use". Lua(La)TeX and Xe(La)TeX can load otf fonts with fontspec, but LaTeX needs another format for font files.

Comment: You might find [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new directory and a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
find `kpsewhich -expand-var='$TEXMFMAIN'`/fonts/tfm -name '*.tfm' -print | \
sed 's@.*/@@; s@\.tfm$@@' | \
xargs sh -c 'for i in "$@"; do (echo $i; echo \\\sample\\\bye) | \
pdftex testfont; mv testfont.pdf $i.pdf; echo $i.pdf; done' sh
```

make it executable and run it. It creates a lot of pdf files for every single font and shape. Another possible solution is to create first a list of all available font:

```
 find `kpsewhich -expand-var='$TEXMFMAIN'`/fonts/tfm -name '*.tfm' -print | sed 's@.*/@@; s@\.tfm$@@' > available_fonts.lst
```

and then running this Perl script, which creates latex test files. It can be 
extend to create one *really* big document:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $i = 0;
my $lst = {};
my $couter_fonts = 0;
my $couter_files = 0;

    open(F, "available_fonts.lst");
    while(<F>){
      chomp;
      $lst->{enc($i++)} = $_;
    }
close F;

open (F, "+>lst_".$couter_files.".tex\n");
print F qq(\\documentclass{article}\n);
print F qq(\n\\begin{document}\n);
foreach(sort keys %{$lst}){
      if (!(++$couter_fonts % 100)){
        $couter_files ++;
        $couter_fonts = 0;
        print F "\\end{document}\n";
        close F;
        open (F, "+>lst_".$couter_files.".tex\n");
        print F qq(\\documentclass{article}\n);
        print F qq(\n\\begin{document}\n);
      }
  print F "\\newfont{\\myFont$_}{ $lst->{$_} }\n";
  print F "\\myFont$_ $lst->{$_} : Sample Text \\\\ \n";
}
print F qq(\\end{document}\n);
close F;

sub enc{
  my $out = "";
  foreach(split //, shift){
    $out .= chr($_+65);
  }
 return $out;
}
```

Comment: Got the LuaLatex example working (and understand the code). Thus, not trying this. However, I appreciate your effort. Thanks!