# Select a font via luaotfload on lua side

Tags: fonts, luatex, luaotfload

I'm creating a glyph node (a capital A) on lua side:

```
\directlua{%
  n = node.new('glyph')
  n.font = font.current()
  n.char = 65 % ASCII code for capital A
}
```

I know how to select current font (`font.current()`). How can I access other fonts that are in `luaotfload` database (say `texgyreschola-regular.otf` as an example)?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but would this be of use to you? <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23630/lualatex-font-table-with-examples/333216#333216>

Comment: @MarkvanAtten Unfortunately no: the font change is done at `TeX` level (`tex.print`). Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I access other fonts that are in luaotfload database
>   (say texgyreschola-regular.otf as an example)?

In order to use a font with Luatex, it needs to be defined
first. The fontloader has a function `fonts.definers.read()`
for that which has the same signature as the `define_font`
callback. Its font lookup calls into Luaotfload’s font index
functionality so you can pass it any valid definition string.

On success, you will receive an object that satisfies the
description in the Luatex manual, ch. 5 “Font structure” so you
can feed it directly into `font.define()`. It returns the font
id that was assigned by TeX to this particular font which you can
use in the situation you describe.

An example that assigns the font in a callback would be:

```lua
local glyph_t     = nodes.nodecodes.glyph

local fontify = function (id)
  return function (hd)
    for n in node.traverse (hd) do
      if n.id == glyph_t then n.font = id end
    end
    return hd
  end
end

local main = function ()
  local tfmdata = fonts.definers.read
                    ("file:iwona-regular.otf:mode=base", 42*2^16)
  local id = font.define (tfmdata)
  luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter", fontify (id),
                             "userdata.stackexchange.fontify")
  tex.sprint "some text"
end

return main ()
-- vim:ft=lua:sw=2:et
```

The entire TeX document:

```
\input luaotfload.sty
\directlua {dofile "\jobname.lua"}
\bye
```

[image: font definition]

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer. I now need some time to analyse and understand all that :)

Comment: What is the `42*2^16` in the function call?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sizes are in sp.