# Font table for OpenType/TrueType fonts

Tags: fonts

How to print a font table for an OpenType/TrueType font? Can I use the `fonttable` package?

A font table should have all glyphs in a font. Like the following (from *The TeXBook*):
[image]

### Update:

I have created a rather complicated font table for Fira Math based on @egreg's answer. You may find it in [specimen.tex](https://github.com/firamath/firamath/blob/main/docs/firamath-specimen.tex). It has the following features:

- Automatically count the glyphs in the fonts/unicode block;
- Fallback to other fonts for the non-existing glyphs (here I use GNU Unifont);
- Highlight for Unicode Reserved Code Points and Control Codes.

At the end of the specimen, there is a section for the non-Unicode glyphs as well.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with a font table?

Comment: @TeXnician I guess he is referring to something like https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/libertinus/documentation.

Comment: @CampanIgnis The problem is that I don't know how to use `\fonttable` for an OpenType font (with extension .otf/.ttf),  especially those fonts in my system.

Comment: The `\fonttable` command can be used **only** if the `.tfm` file exists in the system for the font.

Comment: @karlkoeller How about using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: As far as I can read in the `fonttable` documentation, this is not possible.

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23670/124577) and try to loop through the code points.

Comment: The link to specimen.tex is dead, could you please fix it? Where can I find it?

Comment: @yannis I have update the link

Answer (score 13):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{longtable,array,xcolor,listings}
\begin{luacode*} 
function print_glyphs(maxCols,maxChars) 
  local id = font.current()         -- geht Font ID
  local fnt = font.getfont(id)
  local col = 1
  local maxU4 = 15*(16^3+16^2+16+1)
  a = {}
  for k, v in pairs(fnt.characters) do
    a [#a + 1] = k
  end
  table.sort(a)
  for i, k in ipairs(a) do
    if i >= maxChars then break end
    if col == 1 then
      if k > maxU4 then
        tex.sprint(string.format("U+%06x", k))
      else
        tex.sprint(string.format("U+%04x", k))
      end
      tex.sprint("&") 
    end
    if (i) then
      tex.sprint(string.format([[\char%i]], k))
    else
     tex.sprint("~")
    end
    if col == maxCols then              -- Line finished?
      tex.sprint([[\\\cline{2-]] .. maxCols+1 .. "} ")  -- Yes
      col = 1                           -- newline
    else
      tex.sprint("&")                   -- no, Print &
      col = col + 1                     -- next column
    end
  end
end
\end{luacode*}


\begin{document}
Latin Modern

\color{black!20}

\begin{longtable}{>{\color{black!50}\ttfamily\footnotesize}r|
                  *{10}{>{\color{black}}p{1.5em}|}}
\cline{2-11}
\endhead

%\directlua{print_glyphs(10,1360)} \\ \cline{2-11}
\directlua{print_glyphs(10,65463)} \\ \cline{2-11}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

With XeTeX, making chunks of 512 characters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\OTfonttable}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  #1
  \int_gset:Nn \g_fonttable_rows_int
   { \int_div_truncate:nn { \XeTeXlastfontchar \font + 15 } { 16 } }
  \int_gset:Nn \g_fonttable_chunks_int
   { \int_div_truncate:nn { \g_fonttable_rows_int + 31 } { 32 } }
  \group_end:
  \fonttable_make:n { #1 }
 }

\int_new:N \g_fonttable_rows_int
\int_new:N \g_fonttable_chunks_int
\seq_new:N \l_fonttable_rows_seq
\tl_new:N \l_fonttable_font_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \fonttable_make:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_fonttable_font_tl { #1 }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 0 } { 1 } { \g_fonttable_chunks_int - 1 }
   {
    \seq_clear:N \l_fonttable_rows_seq
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { 0 } { 1 } { 31 }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nx \l_fonttable_rows_seq
       {
        \fonttable_setup: \int_to_Hex:n { ##1*32 + ####1 }x &
        \fonttable_char:n { \int_eval:n { ##1*512 + ####1*16 + 0 } } &
        \fonttable_char:n { \int_eval:n { ##1*512 + ####1*16 + 1 } } &
        \fonttable_char:n { \int_eval:n { ##1*512 + ####1*16 + 2 } } &
        \fonttable_char:n { \int_eval:n { ##1*512 + ####1*16 + 3 } } &
        \fonttable_char:n { \int_eval:n { ##1*512 + ####1*16 + 4 } } &
        \fonttable_char:n { \int_eval:n { ##1*512 + ####1*16 + 5 } } &
        \fonttable_char:n { \int_eval:n { ##1*512 + ####1*16 + 6 } } &
        \fonttable_char:n { \int_eval:n { ##1*512 + ####1*16 + 7 } } &
        \fonttable_char:n { \int_eval:n { ##1*512 + ####1*16 + 8 } } &
        \fonttable_char:n { \int_eval:n { ##1*512 + ####1*16 + 9 } } &
        \fonttable_char:n { \int_eval:n { ##1*512 + ####1*16 + 10 } } &
        \fonttable_char:n { \int_eval:n { ##1*512 + ####1*16 + 11 } } &
        \fonttable_char:n { \int_eval:n { ##1*512 + ####1*16 + 12 } } &
        \fonttable_char:n { \int_eval:n { ##1*512 + ####1*16 + 13 } } &
        \fonttable_char:n { \int_eval:n { ##1*512 + ####1*16 + 14 } } &
        \fonttable_char:n { \int_eval:n { ##1*512 + ####1*16 + 15 } } 
       }
     }
    \begin{tabular}{|r|*{16}{c|}}
    \cline{2-17}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
      \ttfamily 0 &
      \ttfamily 1 &
      \ttfamily 2 &
      \ttfamily 3 &
      \ttfamily 4 &
      \ttfamily 5 &
      \ttfamily 6 &
      \ttfamily 7 &
      \ttfamily 8 &
      \ttfamily 9 &
      \ttfamily A &
      \ttfamily B &
      \ttfamily C &
      \ttfamily D &
      \ttfamily E &
      \ttfamily F \\
    \hline
    \seq_use:Nn \l_fonttable_rows_seq { \\ \hline } \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}\clearpage
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \fonttable_setup: { \ttfamily $\vphantom{\big|}$ }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \fonttable_char:n
 {
  \tl_use:N \l_fonttable_font_tl
  \iffontchar\font #1 \symbol{#1} \fi
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newfontface{\test}{Old Standard}

\begin{document}

\OTfonttable{\normalfont}

\end{document}
```

The argument to `\OTfonttable` can be any font selector, in the example it is `\normalfont`, but it could be `\test` for Old Standard. This will produce 126 pages for `\normalfont`, that is, Latin Modern Roman (235 for Old Standard).

[image]

Comment: Well, sometimes it will print too many blank lines... I know it's not easy, but is there any method to ignore these blank symbols (e.g. most fonts don't have CJK characters)?

Comment: @Stone-Zeng It'll probably be easier to ignore blank lines by virtue of the way the table's formatted - just ignoring blank symbols would de-align everything.

Comment: @Stone-Zeng This won't go past the block with the last character present in the font. The chunks are built one by one, or memory would be exhausted. It wouldn't be too difficult to avoid printing a completely blank chunk.