# using glyphs in the Corporate Use or Microsoft Symbol Areas

Tags: fonts, luaotfload

Since updating TeX Live yesterday (`luaotfload` was among the packages updated, to version 2.9, dated 2018/09/24), I’m having difficulty with glyphs in the Corporate Use Area and the MicroSoft Symbol Area.

For example, here is a glyph in Coelacanth which FontForge reports is named `uniF58C`:

[image: FontForge screenshot]

However, the following produces a page which is blank except for the page number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Coelacanth}
\begin{document}


^^^^f58c

\symbol{"F58C}

\symbol{62860}% a converter called gbase tells me that f58c = 62860

\char62860
\end{document}
```

The `\fontchar` macro described at [access all characters in an OpenType font with LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120762) likewise produces thin air.

Searching for the glyph name `uniF58C` in `coelacanth.lua` yields no result.

The only method I’ve found that works since the update is to make a font table as explained at [Font table for OpenType/TrueType fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380780). Then I can see that the glyph is `U+0f0366`, which can be converted to 983910, and both `\symbol{"0F0366}` and `\symbol{983910}` give the glyph desired.

My question is how to understand this change. Is is just a bug or an intended change? And why is there so little likeness between the information provided by FontForge and that obtained from the font table?

Comment: luaotfload has been updated to the current context fontloader. So in one sense the change is intended. To know if it is a bug I will have to pass the question to the context mailing list. Can you please open an issue at https://github.com/u-fischer/luaotfload/issues so that I don't forget it.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer  It’s https://github.com/u-fischer/luaotfload/issues/7

Comment: I think if will be repaired latest at the end of the week.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generic/context fontloader moved "all private chars in the font to a dedicated private range" and so broke the access of this glyphs. If this change is permanent (unclear yet) all packages and documents which access such glyphs with `\char` will probably have to adapt their code for lualatex.

### Edit 2018-10-04

With todays update of luaotfload the problem should be resolved.

### Currently available work-arounds

#### use an older fontloader

- Get the 2018-07-20 (or 2018-07-20-patched) fontloader from https://github.com/u-fischer/fontloader-archive/tree/master/archive
- create a luaotfload.conf in the search path with

  [run]
  fontloader= fontloader-reference-2018-07-20.lua;

#### access with a lua function

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Coelacanth}
\newcommand\byunicode[1]{\directlua{
      for k, v in pairs(fonts.hashes.identifiers[font.current()].characters) do
          if v.unicode == #1 then
              tex.print(utf.char(k))
              break
          end
      end
 }}


\begin{document}

\byunicode{62860} \byunicode{\number"F58C}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Ulrike! I’m just catching up with [the thread on the ConTeXt list](https://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg89146.html). Hans wonders what the use of these Coelacanth glyphs is: I don’t know. My real use case involves some Goudy fleurons, but I prefer to illustrate problems with freely available fonts if possible.

Comment: I've created alternative version which builds character table in the first use of `\byunicode`, the subsequent calls are more efficient, as it uses the cached version: https://gist.github.com/michal-h21/5922487ed74f3c1b6a34c49904971b0d

Comment: @michal.h21 nice. If we need something like this permantly we certain should use such a cache (and something so that `\byunicode{"F58C}` works without the \number).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've updated the gist so it supports the `\byunicode{"F58C}`

Comment: Seems to work on macOS. `:-)`

Comment: @egreg Uff ;-).