# How do you select individual end alternate/swash characters with LuaLaTeX and fontspec?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, opentype, directlua, garamond

## Basic Problem Statement

---

I would like to enable some (but not all) stylistic alternate ".end" characters from an OpenType font, on condition that they replace *terminal* characters in a word.

Unfortunately, using the `+salt` feature enables them *globally* throughout text, which I do not want.

So far, I have tried using `\directlua` to build a `chainsubstitution`, then add it via `RawFeature`, but this is producing very odd results.

I expect this is likely an error in usage of `\directlua` on my part---one for which I would greatly appreciate correction.

Indeed, to me, my approach seems a bit of a hack, particularly when it comes to listing all the conditions to trigger substitution. If there is an altogether different method for making this substitution smartly, I am happy to hear about it.

## MWE

---

This is a simple example of the problem. I am using Adobe Garamond Premier Pro. Regrettably, I am unaware of a free choice at hand which features the same ".end" characters for this situation.

For ease, (I think) I am setting "a.end" to replace "a" whenever "a" occurs just before a period.

With this snippet, the output is as expected only with the normal Roman and boldface fonts. All italic shapes somehow produce the "d.end" character instead.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\directlua{
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "asub",
    type = "chainsubstitution",
    lookups = {
      {
        type = "substitution",
        data = {
          ["a"] = "a.end",
        },
      },
    },
    data = {
      rules = {
        {
          after  = { { "." } },
          current = { { "a" } },
          lookups = { 1 },
        },
      },
    },
  }
}

\setmainfont[{RawFeature=+asub}]{Garamond Premier Pro}

\begin{document}

a.

{\itshape a. } 

{\bfseries a. }

{\bfseries\itshape a. }

\end{document}
```

### MWE Output

---

[image: MWE Output]

### Notes

---

- Using `+salt` **does** produce the correct "a.end" glyph, no matter what choice of bold and/or italic. On checking the different OTF files with FontForge, I see the "a.end" glyph is not in the same slot for each font, but the name is always the same.
- This is just one example of such a broken substitution. The "h.end" character behaves similarly.

Comment: Does your font support `Contxtuals=Final`?

Comment: @Davislor Sadly, no, Garamond Premier Pro does not. I checked `otfinfo` for each of the fonts, and `fina` is unlisted, confirmed by `fontspec` warning in console output on trying to add the feature. But that is a good point; it would surely make this a simpler matter were it available.

Comment: Unrelated: use a typesetting class (like `article`, say) for an MWE; `minimal` class is "regrettably" named and was intended to test for package-loading dependencies - it defines normalsize font and that's about it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided/42115

Comment: It would be difficult to track down, but I suspect a bug in the fonts. Trying the MWE with Brioso Pro, which is another Adobe type family containing `a.end` and `d.end` in both roman and italic, I get the expected results in the regular and bold roman, but the final form of `à` in the regular and bold italic. But with [Le Monde Livre Classic](https://typofonderie.com/fonts/le-monde-livre-classic-family/), the output of the MWE is perfect.

Comment: The only other font family I have with the necessary glyphs is [LCT Sbire](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/lct/sbire/). The output is as expected in the upright faces, but shows an alternate ampersand in the italic faces.

Comment: We make progress. Using https://gist.github.com/michal-h21/5922487ed74f3c1b6a34c49904971b0d by @michal.h21 (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/453224 for the context), we find that — in Garamond Premier Pro — `a.end` corresponds to 983046 and `d.end` to 983047, whereas in the italic `a.end` is 983045 and `d.end` is 983046. So the problem becomes making different features for the upright and the italic, referencing these numbers. Not sure I can do it — certainly not before this busy semester is done, but maybe someone else with the fonts can pursue this sooner.

Comment: @Thérèse Thank you so much for all this information, and for this resource to find the corresponding character numbers. The problem goes deeper than I first expected. This explains to me how the swap is happening with the italic fonts. I am still puzzled as to how the `+salt` feature gets it correct every time.

Comment: can you try with the dev version of luaotfload? You need to clone the git repo, switch to the dev branch and then l3build install will install it in your texmfhome (if you have texlive) in `tex\latex-dev`. You can then test it by compiling with `lualatex-dev`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the instructions; I had never tried installing the dev version from github until now. Unfortunately, the output of the MWE (with the class changed from `minimal` to `article` for safety) is the same.

Comment: @Thérèse you are sure that you used the new version? The log-file should show something like fontloader-2021-09-14.lua and `luaotfload 2021-05-21 3.19-dev`.  I can't test it, but you could open an issue at the luaotfload tracker.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The log opens with “This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.2 (TeX Live 2021)  (format=lualatex-dev 2021.10.24)  5 NOV 2021 07:55” … “Lua module: luaotfload 2021-05-21 3.18 Lua based OpenType font support”. I’ve opened an issue at https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/205 (though someone who understands the innards of fonts would probably describe it better). 3.19???

Comment: @Thérèse this doesn't look as if you actually use the dev version. This should have the version 3.19-dev as I wrote above.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Then I’m afraid I don’t know how to do this. I did `git clone https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload.git`, changed to the directory created, typed `l3build install`, and then `lualatex-dev example.tex`. Any missing steps?

Comment: @Thérèse Before `l3build install`, run `git checkout dev` to switch to the development branch. Otherwise you just reinstall the last released version.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Thank you! Success! The PDF output is at https://www.dropbox.com/s/8o2ojf8vjk23ob1/eg.pdf?dl=0 in case you want to write an answer with an image but don’t have the fonts.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger By the way, I tried the dev version of `luaotfload` with variable fonts. With the last released version, some variable fonts look as if their outlines have been chewed by rats, but with the dev version, almost all of those defects are gone. Excellent work!

Comment: @Thérèse Thank Hans Hagen and the Context guys. All I did was complain and provide example documents... (I noticed the issue while working on variable font support for `harf` mode, but that requires engine changes and therefore has to wait till TeX Live 2022.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by a bug in `luaotfload`. It will be fixed in version 1.19, but until that is released the development version can be used to avoid the error:

Run:

```
git clone --branch dev --depth 1 https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload.git
cd luaotfload
l3build install
```

Then compiling with `lualatex-dev` will use the development version of luaotfload instead of the last release and the code in the question works.