# How can i generate PDF, containing all Glyphs inkl. Unicode positions, from a specific font?

Tags: symbols

How can i generate PDF, containing all Glyphs inkl. Unicode positions, from a specific font? We developed a CJK Font and now we need to find a way, to create a PDF that shows all glyphs with their corresponding Unicode position. Is there a way? thx

Comment: Maybe related: [Create a font table for all available characters for a particular font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98781/82917) and [Font table for OpenType/TrueType fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/380775/82917)