# Access table of available fonts

Tags: fonts, luatex, context

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get a list of all available fonts for luaotfload?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14162/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-available-fonts-for-luaotfload)

I wonder if there is a possibility to display all available fonts in the
normalised form (see below). The [LuaTeX manual](http://www.luatex.org/svn/trunk/manual/luatexref-t.pdf) states in section 4.3.3

> the whole table of TEX fonts is accessible from LUA using a virtual array.

Trying to read this table like this:

```
\starttext
\startluacode

    for i,v in font.each() do
        context(font.fonts[i].fontname)
        context(' ')
    end

\stopluacode
\stoptext
```

yields to a list of the Latin Modern fonts:

[image: result]

Apparently the font table doesn't contain all fonts, it rather contains the
already loaded fonts. I'd like to get a list like the first column of the output of `mtxrun --script fonts --list --all --pattern=*`:

Example (shortened):

```
wncyss10           wncyss10          wncyss10.afm
xits               xits              xits-regular.otf
xitsbold           xitsbold          xits-bold.otf
xitsbolditalic     xitsbolditalic    xits-bolditalic.otf
xitsitalic         xitsitalic        xits-italic.otf
xitsmath           xitsmath          xits-math.otf
xitsmathnormal     xitsmath          xits-math.otf
xitsmathregular    xitsmath          xits-math.otf
xitsnormal         xitsitalic        xits-italic.otf
xitsregular        xits              xits-regular.otf
```

How can this information be accessed from within LuaTeX? The solution should
work in ConTeXt.