# How to pick a specific symbol from a specific font?

Tags: symbols, luatex

Using LuaLatex, I need two very specific symbols from two very specific fonts, namely from the ZapfDingbats and the WingDings font.

I understand how I could use the `fontspec` package to set those fonts as standard fonts for my document. But for obvious reasons, I don't want that.

How do I pick a *specific* symbol from a *specific* font (with LuaLatex)?

While still using PDFLatex, I used the `pifont` package to get the Dingbats character:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
\ding{113}
\end{document}
```

Doesn't work for WingDings, though, which is why I switched to LuaLatex. However, not only did I understand that using such "font packages" is deprecated with LuaLatex, but I also don't have a clue how I'd go about picking a specific symbol from the WingDings font...

Comment: Use the \fontspec command to switch temporarly to your font.

Comment: As Ulrike said, you can use the \fontspec command. If you are using always the same symbol, you can build a special command to insert this symbol, based on the same \fontspec command.

Comment: Special case of [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249/250119).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\wingdingsfont{Wingdings}
\newcommand\wingdings[1]{{\wingdingsfont\symbol{#1}}}
\usepackage{fonttable}

\begin{document}
\wingdings{40} 123-4567-8900

\fonttable{Wingdings}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice, this solved 50% of my problem. Now all I have to do is to find out by which name to load the *Dingbats* font under LuaLaTex (which obviously exists in my installation as the `pifont` package used it under PdfLatex). "Zapf Dingbats" didn't work, "pzd" and numerous variations didn't, either. *This* part of LaTeX (fonts) gives me headaches...

Comment: @DevSolar: You can load and use it as you would load and use it with pdflatex.

Comment: @DevSolar: For LuaTeX, see [How do I get a list of all available fonts for luaotfload?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14162/2674). For traditional TeX fonts, you'd better use a font package. It is a little more difficult to use traditional TeX symbol fonts directly, see also [Is there a list available for all TeX fonts?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12887) and of course [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Huh? I thought these font packages were deprecated under LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @DevSolar: I wouldn't recommend such font packages for normal text - you would run into problem with encodings and copy&paste - but for symbols I don't see why you shouldn't use them. I certainly use them for chess fonts.

Comment: See also [How do I enter an arbitrary Unicode code point into my document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32514/2674)