# How can I Use the Wingdings symbol?

Tags: fonts, xetex

Does somebody know how can I use Wingdings symbol ?

This code doesn't work :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\wingdingsfont{Wingdings}
\newcommand\wingdings[1]{{\wingdingsfont\symbol{#1}}}
\usepackage{fonttable}

\begin{document}
\wingdings{40} 123-4567-8900

\fonttable{Wingdings}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you do a search on this site? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38404/828 seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: You should tell us more details about your system, software versions and compilation method, because your code compiles correctly here on my system.

Comment: OK. Thanks. 
I'm using Ubuntu, and xelatex with Sublim Text.

Comment: OS X with MacTeX produces same problem. I cannot get good pdf as before.

Comment: Is XeLaTeX expected to dump core just because it can't find a font? (Might be fontconfig.)

Comment: http://ctan.org/pkg/winfonts?

Comment: I try this, but it does not work : http://blog.eitchnet.ch/?p=63 .I didnt manage to install the package !

Comment: Is the WinDings font installed on your system(s)?

Comment: Of course it is. I can choose it in Libreoofice Writer !!

Comment: 'It does not work' is not at all informative. The link you posted does not expand on that comment. (Is the idea that you tried the package earlier after finding that blog?) 'I didn't manage to install the package' is only slightly more informative. This could mean anything - your computer exploded, the phone rang, you ran out of disk space, you couldn't find the keyboard... [I've never used that package. I do use Wingding but my config seems to involve 3 different Wingding fonts and I'm pretty sure I just installed them myself. So I'm not claiming the package does work but we need info.]

Comment: OK. Can you give mea piece of code using a Wingding symbol which is working on your computer please ?

Comment: cfr : How are you using the Wingdings' font without calling a package please ? Thanks (I have installed the font manually).

Comment: I'm afraid that would not have helped. I generated the support files required for the version of Wingdings I have. But those support files would not help you as you have a different version. I only mentioned it as evidence that it is possible to use the truetype version of the font with (pdf)TeX. However, in light of the request in your answer to this question, I will be sure to check that a question is not yours before answering in the future.