# Trigonometric arc

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols

How to be codes for trigonometric arc AB like that:[image]

( not using kpfonts ). Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried? Where have you looked? Why are you stuck? If you are particular about fonts, which are you using? A minimal example would be the ideal way to provide some of this information.

Comment: Are you using XeTeX or LuaTeX?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I can use kpfonts to make it but all fonts in the document changed. Is there a way to make that symbol but reserving all the other fonts. I don't know using XeTex or LuaTex.

Answer (score 3):

You could draw this with `tikz`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}

\newcommand{\curvearc}{\tikz[trim left]{\draw[->] (0,0) to[bend left] (1em,0);}}

\begin{document}

\( \stackrel{\curvearc}{AB} \)

\end{document}
```

If you would like the width of this arrow symbol to vary with the material underneath and then you can use the following more complicated definition:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}

\newlength{\curvearclength}
\newcommand{\curvearcover}[1]{\mathpalette\curvearcoverhelper{#1}}
\newcommand{\curvearcoverhelper}[2]{%
  \settowidth{\curvearclength}{\( #1#2 \)}%
  \setlength{\curvearclength}{0.6\curvearclength}%
  \stackrel{\tikz[trim left]{\draw[->] (0,0) to[bend left] 
    (\the\curvearclength,0);}}{#1#2}}

\begin{document}

\( \curvearcover{AB} \)

\bigskip

\( \curvearcover{IJ} \)

\bigskip

\( \scriptstyle\curvearcover{AB} \)

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newcommand*\curvearc[2][1em]{\overset{\tikz[trim left]\draw[->](0,0)to[bend left]({#1},0);}{#2}}` might be more practical.

Comment: @Manuel Indeed - code now added to make the measuring automatic.

Answer (score 2):

`\usepackage{fourier}`

Then

`$\wideOarc{AB}$`

However, as Andrew Swann noted in a comment, loading the fourier package changes all the fonts in the document.

Comment: This will change all fonts in the document.

Comment: Could you at least convert it to a LuaTeX solution like this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38402/how-to-pick-a-specific-symbol-from-a-specific-font ?

Comment: @percusse, thank you for the suggestion.  However, I am not familiar with XeTeX or LuaTeX.  (I use pdfLaTeX.)