# How to use a specific symbol on an specific font

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

How can I use a specific character of a specific font? And how could I use it in math-mode?

I have tried to use, what I would expect to work:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\specialfont{mathb12}
\newcommand\myroundtarrow{\specialfont\symbol{"FC}}

\begin{document}
\myroundarrow
\end{document}
```

and, amazingly, I DO get the character, but not without a lot of errors on part of `Metafont` and even one from `fontspec` saying it can't find the font:

```
! Package fontspec Error: The font "mathb12/B" cannot be found.
```

I am aware of the Q/A in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38402/how-to-pick-a-specific-symbol-from-a-specific-font) but the solution there produces some of the same errors under TeXLive 2020 xelatex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\newfontfamily` with OpenType or TrueType fonts, not with “legacy” Metafont fonts.

You need to declare the font in the “traditional” way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> mathb5
  <5.5-6.5> mathb6
  <6.5-7.5> mathb7
  <7.5-8.5> mathb8
  <8.5-9.5> mathb9
  <9.5-10.5> mathb10
  <10.5-> mathb12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

% \lefttorightarrow in mathabx
\DeclareMathSymbol{\myroundtarrow}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"FC}

\begin{document}

$\myroundtarrow$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, this is clear now, but I have just one question left: How come, if you click on those error messages you DO end up with a representation of the character?