# Looking for links, pointers to info on type specimen generation

Tags: fonts, xetex, metadata

So far I've found the following:

- **opentype-info.tex** by Jonathan Kew
- **TypeSp01.tex -- TypeSp10.tex** by Stephen Moye
- **t1testpage.exe** by Eddie Kohler

I'm hoping that I've missed a package (or two) as well as other information. I've got >2k fonts on my development machine and I've finally concluded that I desperately need something more dependable than my memory.

opentype-info.tex is set up for XeTeX, TypeSp01-10 for TeX and t1testpage is limited to .pfb files. I'd think that the first two could be rewritten for XeLaTeX and perhaps extended with a Perl script as needed. Any other solutions could be folded in as well.

As an example of extension, the necessary successive runs of **otfinfo.exe** could be formatted and combined with the above. This could all be combined in a sort of grande scheme/stew so that I or anyone else for that matter could make decisions about font usage intelligently.

As I'm typing this I noticed the question about '*Generating a table of glyphs with XeTeX*' which I'll take a look at for obvious reasons. An answer before I even post the question---no wonder I keep coming back to this exchange :)

Comment: Yes, '**Generating...XeTeX**' is quite useful.

Comment: Also remembered **fontsmpl.sty**---needs testing but looks useful.

Comment: you can get list of all available fons with luatex http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14162/2891

Comment: @michal.h21 thanks for the link, although I'd probably re-write it for PerlTeX :)

Comment: @michal.h21  I like the idea of a font database. Could populate it using otfinfo.exe. At a guess the Lua db probably references the fonts in the TeX tree---I could build one based on the installed fonts for my system instead. What fun!

Comment: I think in this database are all accesible fonts - fonts in TeX tree as well as system fonts. I think in file otfl-names.lua there is big lua table, which should be easy to parse with perl

Comment: @michal.h21 I'm running MikTeX 2.9 on Windows 7 Ultimate and there is no otfl-names.lua in the Mik Tree :( There is however a file named mkluatexfontdb.lua which suggests that otfl-names.lua might well exist at some point but not yet. Probably because I don't use LuaTeX? I'll investigate...

Comment: yes, you must run this script first. it is called by fontspec when document is compiled by lualatex

Comment: @michal.h21 at the moment can't get past:`C:\>luatex testLua.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.2-2012060719 (MiKTeX 2.9)

(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)`

Comment: @michal.h21 It would help if I knew what I was doing---it should have been `C:\lulatex testlua.tex` That gives me the sensible error of `! LuaTeX error cannot open C:/Users/hsmyers/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cac
he/generic/names/otfl-names.lua: No such file or directory` which proves that mkluatexfontdb.lua has not yet run. That's next...

Comment: Are there any news here? Did you solve the issue in the meanwhile and are able to provide a self answer? If not, are there any details you can add to the question? That would make it appear on the main page again.

Comment: @Johannes_B This question can be closed out. I did not find or create a solution to the problem but have moved on to other concerns. When I return to the issue I will probably revisit the LuaTex approach...