# Avoid update font name database by luaotfload

Tags: fonts, luatex

I am using `LuaLaTeX` to typesetting documents with system fonts. Compiling needs much time to update the font database: `luaotfload | Updating the font names database:`. I think this update is not necessary, because I do not change the fonts every time. If my assumption is correct, is it possible to avoid this update?

A minimal example that shows the problem:

```
\documentclass[paper = a4]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{blindtext, fontspec}

% Typewriter (\ttfamily)
\setmonofont[BoldFont = VeraMoBd, ItalicFont = VeraMoIt, Scale = MatchLowercase]{VeraMono}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

I used different fonts set by `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont`, but only the mono-spaced `VeraMono` hangs on updating the font names database.

The free font `Bitstream Vera` is available [here](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/ttf-bitstream-vera/1.10/).

Comment: There was a bug in one version which lead to constant recreation of the font database but imho it should be solved. Which TeX system do you use and which luaotfload version?

Comment: I think the first line of my log contains all information: `This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.2-2012080612 (TeX Live 2012/W32TeX) (format=lualatex 2013.4.6)  27 MAY 2013 15:11`

Comment: It doesn't say anything about the luaotfload-version. But I don't think that TL12 was affected by the problem. Run `mkluatexfontdb -vv` on the command line and check if it hangs at some font.

Comment: Sorry. You are right. Is this the version you are looking for: `Package: luaotfload 2012/05/28 v1.27 OpenType layout system`? The command pass through and counts 977 fonts in the database. Furthermore, it shows me the filename of the database.

Comment: Show a complete minimal example that triggers the problem. Try not to use local fonts.

Comment: I add an minimal example to my question.

Comment: I don't have the font but if I use Arial instead there is no problem on my system.

Comment: It is free (`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitstream_Vera`), if you would like to try it: `http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/ttf-bitstream-vera/1.10/` I have no problems with Arial and some other non-standard fonts, too. So its an issue with VeraMono, I think. But how can I solve this?

Comment: Try this fontnames: `\setmonofont[BoldFont = BitstreamVeraSans-Bold, ItalicFont = BitstreamVeraSans-Oblique]{BitstreamVeraSans}
`

Comment: This process without the delay, but it is not the mono spaced font. Take a look at the zero. In mono it has a dot inside, the normal one has not.

Comment: Ah sorry, there is a mono missing, it should naturally be BitstreamVeraSansMono etc.

Comment: Hey Ulrike, that works perfect! How did you get the font name? Do one have to list the fonts like in this post (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14171/14200) and look up the font?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you answer my question with your solution from our discussion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To sum up the discussion in the comments:

`luaotfload` updated the font name databases at each run because the font names where wrong and so `luaotfload` couldn't find the font by name in the database (it did find it in the end as VeraMono is the file name).

The correct call is:

```
\setmonofont[BoldFont = BitstreamVeraSansMono-Bold, ItalicFont = BitstreamVeraSansMono-Oblique]{BitstreamVeraSansMono}
```

The correct font name can be found e.g. in the font selection dialog of some other office application, or in the database created by luaotfload (`otfl-names.lua`  with the older versions of luaotfload (TL2012/current miktex) and `luaotfload-names.lua` in TL2013).

A list of fonts can printed as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14171/14200 (the actual code depends on the luaotfload version).

Comment: With the current version you can simply ``luaotfload-tool --list=*`` to get a list of all font names (and more). Also the ``--find=<name>`` switch gets you feedback on whether the name you request actually matches a font.

Answer (score 0):

If you find this problem on macos. Try rebuilding the database using sudo.

```
sudo luaotfload-tool --update
```

This fixed the issue of the database trying to rebuild on every tex compile.