# LaTeX Font Catalogue in Italic

Tags: fonts, italic

The [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) is a very good place to look for nice fonts easily usable with LaTeX. For instance, one can look for  [all the serif fonts](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/seriffonts.html) to compare them and find the most appropriate one.

Though, I'd like to use some serif fonts but only in italic (for full disclosure, this font will be used for the titles in some Beamer slides, where I use sans-serif fonts). At least on the LaTeX Font Catalogue, there is no list of fonts in italic.

I have then two questions:

- Is there a list of easy-to-use-in-LaTeX fonts, in italic?
- Is there a (reasonably simple) way of producing a document with a list of all fonts installed in the LaTeX distribution? And more precisely a list with an example (say *The quick brown fox jumps over the sleazy dog*) for each font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Virtually all fonts in the catalogue you mention have an italic shape, so that's not really the problem.  To access the italics, you typically use `\emph{<words>}` or `\textit{<words>}`, or the switch `{\itshape <words>}`. Easy.

If you want to make italics the default, then you need to be more tricky.  You can make the `it` shape the defaul if you want (not that I would recommend it in most circumstances), by adding this to your preamble:

```
% \usepackage{mathpazo}% <-- perhaps you have a font family in mind already
\renewcommand{\shapedefault}{it}
```

If you want to test out a bunch of different fonts and see which one has the italics you're hoping for, then you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\setmyfont}[1]{%
  \fontfamily{#1}\fontshape{it}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\test}{The quick brown fox jumped\ldots}
\newcommand{\fonttest}[1]{%
  \setmyfont{#1} Family ``#1'':
  \test\par}

\begin{document}
  \begin{itemize}
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item \fonttest{#1}}
    \docsvlist{lmr, ppl, ptm}% must add to the list manually; see this list
                               % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25251/8528
  \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

If you want to use `luatex` as the engine, then you can easily access all available system fonts using the techniques described in [these answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14162/8528).

If you want to stick to `pdftex` and Type1 fonts, then take a look at Karl Berry's "Fontname"; use `texdoc fontname` if applicable (more complete than above link).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I should have been more precise in my question, but what I was looking for is indeed a list of available fonts *in italic shape*.