# How can I list fonts available to LuaTeX in ConTeXt (TeX Live 2013)?

Tags: luatex, context-mkiv

I've looked at [How do I get a list of all available fonts for luaotfload?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14162/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-available-fonts-for-luaotfload), but the answers don't work for me in TeX Live 2013, at least not without LaTeX. This is because there they rely on the file `otfl-names.lua` under `\luatex-cache\generic\names`; but in my installations of TeX Live 2013 (ConTeXt scheme), the only directory under `\luatex-cache` is `context`, and there is no `otfl-names.lua` that I can find.

P.S. Following [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14162/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-available-fonts-for-luaotfload/14171?noredirect=1#comment321771_14171), I also looked for `luaotfload-names.lua`, but can't find that file either. Do I need to run a program to build it? I looked for `mkluatexfontdb` but no such command seems to exist.

I tried the following ConTeXt mkiv (LuaTeX) document:

```
\starttext
\startluacode
myfonts=dofile(fonts.names.path.path)

for i,v in ipairs(myfonts.mappings) do
 tex.print(-2, v.familyname)
 tex.print(', ')
 tex.print(-2, v.fontname)
 tex.print('\\par')
end

\stopluacode
\stoptext
```

But I get the error:

> ! LuaTeX error [string "\directlua "]:2: attempt to index field 'path'
>   (a nil value)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all you need is a *list* of the registered fonts, you can run

```
mtxrun --script fonts --list --all
```

for Context, and

```
luaotfload-tool --list=*
```

for Lualatex/Luaotfload (see `man 1 luaotfload-tool` for details).

If you did not yet build the font indices you will have to do
so before running above commands, e.g.

```
mtxrun --script fonts --reload
```

and

```
luaotfload-tool --update
```

Comment: Depending on you shell, you might have to escape the asterisk like `luaotfload-tool --list='*'` or `luaotfload-tool --list=\*`.

Answer (score 1):

Following [these comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14162/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-available-fonts-for-luaotfload/14171?noredirect=1#comment321788_14171), I found a font name database at `~/.texlive2013/texmf-var/luatex-cache/context/.../fonts/data/names.tma`

It would still be nice to have a program to generate the list in an easy-to-read format, but this will do for now.

Update:

I received this code from Wolfgang Schuster:

```
% When you want list of all fonts in the database you can do this with 
% a few macros in your document which are provided for this purpose.

% nofruns=1

\setupbodyfont[10pt]

\starttext

\dolookupfontbyspec{filename=*}

\starttabulate
\dorecurse{\dolookupnoffound}
  {\expanded{\NC \dolookupgetkeyofindex{fontname}{\recurselevel} \EQ \dolookupgetkeyofindex{filename}{\recurselevel} \NC\NR}}
\stoptabulate

\stoptext
```