# How to select a font for the main Chinese character and another font for its Furigana?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, cjk, xecjk

The objective is to make a list of Japanese vocabularies with Kanji stroke order for the main characters, its furigana (small kana characters placed above the main characters), and its meaning (in English).

I have `KanjiStrokeOrders` font installed in my machine. I download it from [this site (click)](http://www.nihilist.org.uk/).

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,12pt,preview,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{ruby}
\renewcommand\rubysep{.05ex}

\AtBeginDocument{\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont}

\let\temp\ruby
\renewcommand\ruby[2]{\temp {\fontsize{60}{60}\fontspec{KanjiStrokeOrders}\selectfont#1}{#2}}

\def\mean#1{: \textcolor{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \ruby{会}{かい}\ruby{社}{しゃ}　\mean{company}
    \item \ruby{朝}{あさ} \mean{morning}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

### without `xeCJK`

Without `xeCJK` the main  characters appears but their furigana disappear.

[image]

### with `xeCJK`

With `xeCJK` the furiganas appear but the main characters no longer use `KanjiStrokeOrder` fonts.

[image]

### Question:

How should I select the font to achieve my objective mentioned above?

Comment: I use `xelatex` but I actually want to use `pdflatex` if possible.

Comment: Without xecjk you must select a suitable font for your furigana too -- the default font selected by fontspec don't have this chars.  With xecjk the problem is that xecjk automatically switch to a specific font when it encounter the first cjk-character. And so it overwrites your font selection. Imho you should stick to xelatex or lualatex. With pdflatex writing cjk is quite complicated -- and setting up cjk-fonts for pdflatex is quite difficult.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: How do I know the name of font to be used for the furigana?

Comment: Look at the answer of Malipivo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my first experiment without `xeCJK`.

```
% run: xelatex mal-furigana.tex
\documentclass[border=12pt,12pt,preview,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\kanji{KanjiStrokeOrders_v3.001.ttf}
\newfontfamily\furigana{FandolSong-Regular}
\usepackage{ruby}
\renewcommand\rubysep{.05ex}
\AtBeginDocument{\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont}
\let\temp\ruby
\renewcommand\ruby[2]{\temp 
  {\fontsize{60}{60}\kanji#1}%
  {\furigana#2}
  }% end of \ruby...
\def\mean#1{: \textcolor{red}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \ruby{会}{かい}\ruby{社}{しゃ}　\mean{company}
    \item \ruby{朝}{あさ} \mean{morning}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe, experiment without xeCJK]

**Update 1:** This is the experiment with `xeCJK` using a new font family.

```
% run: xelatex mal-furigana.tex
%\documentclass[border=12pt,12pt,preview,varwidth]{standalone}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{ruby}
\renewcommand\rubysep{.05ex}
\setCJKmainfont{KanjiStrokeOrders}
\newCJKfontfamily\furigana{FandolSong-Regular}
\AtBeginDocument{\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont}
\let\temp\ruby
\renewcommand\ruby[2]{\temp 
  {\fontsize{60}{60}#1}%\selectfont\setmainfont{KanjiStrokeOrders}
  {\fontsize{20}{20}\furigana#2}
  }% end of \ruby...
\def\mean#1{: \textcolor{red}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \ruby{会}{かい}\ruby{社}{しゃ}　\mean{company}
    \item \ruby{朝}{あさ} \mean{morning}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe with xeCJK]

**Update 2:** This is the promised version without `xeCJK` and `ruby`. I am placing furigana by means of `tikz` package. We can run `xelatex` and `lualatex`. Setting up a TTF/OTF font for `pdflatex` engine is possible (but we are limited to 256 glyphs per font file), but it's out-of-date these days. I enclose the code and its preview.

```
% run: xelatex or lualatex mal-furi-general.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newfontfamily\kanji{KanjiStrokeOrders_v3.001.ttf}
\newfontfamily\furigana{FandolSong-Regular}
\def\mkanji{\fontsize{60}{60}\kanji}
\def\mfurigana{\fontsize{15}{15}\furigana}
\def\mruby#1#2{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(temp.base)]
  \node(temp){\mkanji#1};
  \node[anchor=center,yshift=0.5ex]at(temp.north){\mfurigana#2};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }% End of \mruby...
\def\mean#1{ \textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcount\malc \malc=0
\def\mterm{\par
  \advance\malc by 1\relax%
  \the\malc. %
  }% End of \mterm...
\begin{document}
\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont
\mterm \mruby{会}{かい}\mruby{社}{しゃ}\mean{company}
\mterm \mruby{朝}{あさ}\mean{morning}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe: without xeCJK and ruby]

Comment: what is the pros and cons of with and without `xeCJK`?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter much in these small examples with several glyphs, but I am not the right person to answer your question. However, I believe we could even prepare a version without `xeCJK` and `ruby`.

Comment: `Fandol-Song` is actually a Chinese font, but we should use a Japanese font here. `IPAMincho` or `IPAexMincho` are suiltable Japanese fonts preinstlled in TeX Live.

Comment: @LeoLiu Are you sure it's needed in this case (I'm using font used by the `ruby` package)? The kana/glyphs looks fine, I like them. That font is used for displaying furigana (hiragana+katakana) only, not for the kanjis.

Comment: @Malipivo: I'm not sure if there would be any other kanjis in the explanations. Personally I would choose a Japanese font for safety.

Comment: The usage of `\setmainfont`, `\setCJKsansfont` is quite strange to me. I'll fix it if you don't mind.

Comment: @LeoLiu Of course, go ahead! `\newCJKfontfamily` is a better way, I was quite happy that it/something was working for me, hopefully commands in the `xeCJK` manual are in English/Latin script, so I wasn't that lost. :-)

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer: A document which contains one or two complete sentences will need `xeCJK` for proper line breaking; for longer documents automatical font switching via `xeCJK` makes life easier. But in your example `xeCJK` is not necessary and you can typeset the document a little faster.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to know how to select font for Chinese characters, you should know which font do you want to use for every character, and you need to know the basic functions of `xeCJK` if you use it.

### The fonts

In your example, you should to use a special font KanjiStrokeOrders for 漢字 (kanji), and use another Japanese font, which is NOT properly specified in your document, for 振り仮名 (furigana).

If you don't set a proper font, you cannot typeset any CJK characters at all, because the default Latin Modern fonts do not contain CJK glyphs.

In contrast, if you use v3.2.10 or later version of `xeCJK`, Chinese fonts Fandol will be loaded with a warning:

```
*************************************************
* xeCJK warning: "fandol"
* 
* Fandol is being set as the default font for CJK text.
* Please make sure it has been properly installed.
*************************************************
```

That's why the furiganas appear with `xeCJK` in your document even if you didn't specify a Japanese font.

### Usage of `xeCJK`

The document of `xeCJK` v3.x is only available in Chinese, I'm sorry.

The main purposes of `xeCJK` are

- To select different fonts for CJK characters and Latin characters automatically;
- To get proper line breaking;
- To do punctation kerning.

The basic function is font switching, whose syntax is the same as `fontspec` package:

- `\setCJKmainfont` — `\setmainfont`
- `\setCJKsansfont` — `\setsansfont`
- `\setCJKmonofont` — `\setmonofont`
- `\newCJKfontfamily` — `\newfontfamily`
- `\CJKfontspec` — `\fontspec`

### Solution

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass[border=12pt,12pt,preview,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{ipaexm.ttf} % For furigana and other Japanese characters
\newCJKfontfamily\strokefont{KanjiStrokeOrders_v3.001.ttf} % For stroke order

\usepackage{ruby}
\renewcommand\rubysep{.05ex}
\renewcommand\rubysize{0.2}
\let\oldruby\ruby
\renewcommand\ruby[2]{{\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\oldruby{\strokefont#1}{#2}}}

\def\mean#1{: \textcolor{red}{#1}}

\AtBeginDocument{\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \ruby{会}{かい}\ruby{社}{しゃ}　\mean{company}
    \item \ruby{朝}{あさ} \mean{morning}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do you know the filename  of the font you want to import? Is it necessary to know the filename rather than just the font name? I have no documentation to read about these questions.

Comment: I'm the one to be blamed. You are fine in `xelatex` using font names and filenames, but when I'm using `lualatex`+`fontspec` I'm having difficulties to load a font using font name containing spaces. Therefore I tend to use filenames instead (it's easy to find the file among system fonts).

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer: I know that there is a `ipaex` Japanese font package installed in TeX distributions, so I can search it. You can access a font via its filename if it is installed in TeX distribution (e.g. TeX Live) and can be searched via `kpsewhich` library. You can access a font via is family name if it is installed in your OS and can be searched via `fontconfig` library (for Windows and Linux) or OS API (for Mac). For Windows and Linux, `fc-list` tells you the fonts can be used via family name.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer: This may help: [How to get a list of all available (TTF-) Fonts with XeTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12902/2674) Actually you can also get the filename via `fc-list`. For LuaTeX, see [How can I list fonts available to LuaTeX in ConTeXt (TeX Live 2013)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142396/2674)