# Change fontsize for CJK characters?

Tags: fonts, fontsize, cjk, xecjk

I have the following example:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, parskip=full]{article} % twoside can be added if two sided margin layout is desired
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin={30mm, 20mm},hmargin={30mm, 25mm},includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage{xpinyin}
\xpinyinsetup{ratio=0.5, vsep=1em, multiple={\color{red}}, font=Liberation Sans}

\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode}
\setCJKmainfont[]{WenQuanYi Micro Hei}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text, Scale=MatchLowercase} % what does this do? -- influences how quotes are rendered
\setmainfont[Scale=1]{Open Sans}
\setmonofont{Liberation Mono}
\DeclareMathSizes{10}{10}{8}{7}

\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\begin{document}

There is latin text here.

\begin{pinyinscope}
我有一个送给你的礼物．
\end{pinyinscope}

\end{document}
```

There is latin letters, which I want to still have the default font size, but all Chinese characters shall be font size 13, or 14pt or something like that. How do I set their size globally?

I don't want to mix content and layout too much, so surrounding a block of Chinese characters with `\large{...}` is not a good option.

Answer (score 2):

I found this by further searching the web:

```
\setCJKmainfont[Scale=1.4]{WenQuanYi Micro Hei}
```

This multiplies the main font size with the factor 1.4 to use that as a font size for CJK characters.

Answer (score 0):

Very nice!
For some readers, it might be interesting to see that this answer

[how-to-select-a-font-for-the-main-chinese-character-and-another-font-for-its-furigana](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178744/how-to-select-a-font-for-the-main-chinese-character-and-another-font-for-its-fur)

also provides a solution as you can tune the fontsize with fontspec.
However, you need to write the Pinyin yourself in that case.